# Waht is () => //sample code in js or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, task, multitasking

What name of `()=> //codes`

waht does it do? or what is its purpose. Example in c#

```
 List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();
 var taskCustomer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
   using (NorthContext dbContext=new NorthContext())
   {
       model.CustomerList = dbContext.Customers.Where(
       cus=>cus.ContactName.Contains(search)).ToList();
   }
});
Tasks.Add(taskCustomer);
```

Example in js

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.onResize());
```

this.onResize();

Comment: It’s just an anonymous function, also called lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **`javascript/Typescript`** , Its called **`arrow function`**,

**`FROM DOCS`**

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

In **`C#`**,

It is called a **[`lambda expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)**.

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda
>   expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as
>   arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda
>   expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query
>   expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This `() => {//...}` is called lambda expression in **C#**. It's an easy way to define a method and pass it as an argument to another mehtod. In this **specific** case the method you define has no parameters and does whatever you specify inside the curly braces. More formally as it is stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

> A lambda expression is an anonymous function that you can use to
>   create delegates or expression tree types. By using lambda
>   expressions, you can write local functions that can be passed as
>   arguments or returned as the value of function calls. Lambda
>   expressions are particularly helpful for writing LINQ query
>   expressions.

On the other hand, in **JavaScript**, this is called **arrow function** and as it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: It could also be used to define a method that takes arguments.

Comment: also docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: @JonathanWood I edited my answer to make it more clear. Thanks